# sql server comparing numeric filed with a string that contains comma separated numbers using IN command

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I hope this is not too bad of a logic that I am after.
I have a web page which has a list/select box. A user may select one or many of the items from the list.
This process sends each items database id to the server in following format

```
String listOfIdees= '12,14,54,87'
```

I pass this cs list to stored procedure..where I want to check if none of these records already exist or exist using following format

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE recId in (@listOfIdees)
```

This of course throws an error that

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12,14,54,87' to data type int.
```

If user selects one record, that is converted to int correctly but when there is a comma separated list then there is exception

Can some kind soul guide that what is the best approach to check records existing in such manner as I don't think I can pass an array of int from my web application to stored procedure?

Comment: The SQL Server expert and MVP Erland Sommarskog has written extensively about this for example in this article: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html It should provide all information you need.

Comment: Also, this has been asked and answered several times before.

Comment: my apologies I did do a search but I guess my search query was not correct...thanks for your help regardless

Comment: No worries, it can be hard to find the appropriate earlier answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to resolve this:

Just paste this into an empty query window and execute. Adapt to your needs...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, SomeValue VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'value 1')
,(2,'value 2')
,(3,'value 3')
,(4,'value 4')
,(5,'value 5');

DECLARE @ListOfIDs VARCHAR(20)='1,3,5';

WITH ListOfIDs AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<root><r>'+REPLACE(@ListOfIDs,',','</r><r>')+'</r></root>' AS XML) AS IDsAsXML
)
,ListOfIDsResolved AS
(
    SELECT x.y.value('.','int') AS ID
    FROM ListOfIDs
    CROSS APPLY ListOfIDs.IDsAsXML.nodes('/root/r') x(y)
)
SELECT * FROM @tbl AS tbl
INNER JOIN ListOfIDsResolved ON tbl.ID=ListOfIDsResolved.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to use CHARINDEX like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
 WHERE CHARINDEX(
    ',' + CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ',', 
    ',' + @listOfIdees + ','
    ) > 0
```

Comment: simple, but slow... And you should be sure, that there are no blanks in the given ID string :-)